# How to add classpath hilt-android-gradle-plugin in android studio chipmunk and higher

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

earlier we could add dagger-hilt using this in `root build.gradle file:`

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
    }
}
```

how can we add this in android studio chipmunk and higher

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.43' apply false
```

You can use this code

Answer (score 3):

First, add a Plugin in Root level Gradle like below

```
plugins {
  // other plugins...
  id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.43.2' apply false
}
```

And then add Plugin in App level Gradle like below

```
plugins {
  // other plugins...
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}
```

For reference please read this documentation:
https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup